# Failed to connect to OpenTok. Response code: Authentication failed while creating a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opentok

I am trying to integrate video call to my web application implemented using Ruby on Rails and opentok. Currently the app throws an error for "Create Session" 
**Failed to connect to OpenTok. Response code: Authentication failed while creating a session. API Key: 3548532**

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :config_opentok,:except => [:index]

require "opentok"

def index
  @rooms = Room.where(:public => true).order("created_at DESC")
  @new_room = Room.new
end

def create
  api_key = "3548532"       # Replace with your OpenTok API key.
  api_secret = "my secret key"  # Replace with your OpenTok API secret.

  opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new api_key, api_secret
  session = opentok.create_session :media_mode => :routed
  session_id = session.session_id
  params[:room][:sessionId] = session.session_id

  @new_room = Room.new(params[:room])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @new_room.save
      format.html { redirect_to("/party/"+@new_room.id.to_s) }
    else
      format.html { render :controller => ‘rooms’, :action => “index” }
    end
  end
end

def party
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])

  @tok_token = @opentok.generate_token @room.sessionId 
end

end
```

Party.html.erb:

```
 <div id="invitation">Invite your friends! Share the url of this page http://localhost:3030/party/<%= @room.id %></div>
<div id="videobox">

</div>
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/v0.91/js/TB.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var apiKey =  3548532;
    var sessionId = "<%= @room.sessionId %>";
    var token = "<%= @tok_token %>";

    var session;


TB.setLogLevel(TB.DEBUG);
//session.connect(apiKey, token);
   var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);
    session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', sessionConnectedHandler);
    session.addEventListener('streamCreated', streamCreatedHandler);
    session.connect(apiKey, token);


 var publisher;
    function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
      publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, 'videobox');
      session.publish(publisher);

      // Subscribe to streams that were in the session when we connected
      subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
    }

    function streamCreatedHandler(event) {
      // Subscribe to any new streams that are created
      subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
    }

    function subscribeToStreams(streams) {
      for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
        // Make sure we don't subscribe to ourself
        if (streams[i].connection.connectionId == session.connection.connectionId) {
          return;
        }

        // Create the div to put the subscriber element in to
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + streams[i].streamId);
        document.body.appendChild(div);

        // Subscribe to the stream
        session.subscribe(streams[i], div.id);
      }
    }
</script>
```

Why is the authentication failing? 
I trying to follow the instructions from https://github.com/loganathan-s/vide0-chat-using-tokbox

Thank you

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. 
It looks like you're using an older version of the API and the link you're referring to is not an official TokBox repo. I recommend checking out the following repo: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-Ruby-SDK/tree/master/sample/HelloWorld

Comment: I have looked at the above link. The example is in Sinatra framework. I am not familiar with the framework and I am building on rails. Is there any documentation available for rails? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hi Uma, I've answered the question below with a code sample - hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Manik, Also I think my issue was that I used my account API key and Secret key. It seems that I must have created a project and generate API key and secret key for that project and used that pair(instead of the account pair) to create the session.

Comment: Hi Uma, you should use the project API key and secret to create sessions, generate tokens, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Based on the sample application you shared, it looks like you're using a deprecated version (v0.91) of the OpenTok JS SDK.

Here's the link to the latest [OpenTok JS SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/): `https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js`

Please try the code below to create a session, connect, publish, and subscribe:

```
const session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
const publisher = OT.initPublisher();

session.on({
  streamCreated: event => {
    session.subscribe(event.stream);
  },
  sessionConnected: event => {
    session.publish(publisher);
  },
});

session.connect(token, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`There was an error connecting to the session: ${err}`);
  }
});
```

Please note the following key changes:

- The global variable used to refer to the OpenTok object is `OT` not `TB`
- The `initSession` method requires both the `apiKey` and the `sessionId` instead of just the `apiKey`.
- The `connect` method only requires the `token` instead of the `apiKey`, and `token`.
- The `initPublisher` method does not require the `apiKey`.
- The `addEventListener` methods have been deprecated, please use `.on` to set event listeners.

For more information on the web samples, please refer to the following sample [project](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Basic%20Video%20Chat).

Comment: Super useful! Thanks so much for the instructions!